# Guidance needed in finding scattering amplitude

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

If I have the Lagrangian 
$$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma ^\mu \partial_\mu - m)\psi -g\bar{\psi}i\gamma^5\phi\psi,$$ where $g$ is a coupling constant.

How to find the scattering amplitude for
$$
\phi \psi \to \phi \psi
$$
What I only learned in class was electron-electron scattering and electron-proton scattering and can't seem to relate this case above to any of them. I ask only for guidance. Please and thank you!

Comment: "The" scattering amplitude does not exist. In general, one computes such amplitudes via [Feynman diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am aware of that, I just dont know how to deal with this problem since I can't relate this case to the e-e scattering nor to the e- p+ scattering. Just how to start?

Comment: I think you are confused about the definition of the scattering amplitude. There is no such thing as the scattering amplitude of a theory. Rather, one defines a scattering amplitude for a certain scattering process in a certain theory. In your question, you have given us the theory - namely fermions coupled to a Yukawa scalar - but you have not given us the particular scattering process whose scattering amplitude you are interested in. Can you rephrase this question to include this?

Comment: @Prahar I am very confused, true. I am still struggling with this. My later aim is to find differential cross section for a process that has pions scattered off by Dirac particles. But first I write down the Lagrangian above and now I should find the scattering amplitude. I have searched long for feynmann rules for this theory but I still can't relate to my e- e- scattering case I learned back in class. Thank you a lot for you time!!

Comment: Aren't you missing kinetic terms for $\phi$ .?

Comment: @Fluctuations - Again, can you please tell me what scattering amplitude you are interested in? Is it an $e^- e^-$ scattering? or a pion scattering or a $e^+ e^-$ scattering? which one?

Comment: @Fluctuations - I suggest that in the question, you copy down word-for-word the problem that you are struggling with and not your interpretation of it. Maybe then we can clarify your doubts.

Comment: @Prahar "Write the scattering amplitude for the process where pion particles are scattered off by Dirac particles"

Comment: @Prahar Pions are pseudo-scalar particles as far as I know and that's why I wrote the Lagrangian the way it is above.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Does it really have to have this kinetic term? I don't really know.. The problem didn't say there was a scalar field or something..

Comment: Well, without the kinetic term, then your interaction term becomes a constraint (if you vary with respect to $\phi$), or it has an undetermined external function (if you don't vary with respect to $\phi$)

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Is my Lagrangian wrong? I am totally confused? :(

Comment: Your professor probably just wanted there to be an implied $\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi$ term.

Comment: @Fluctuations - So the process you are interested in is $\psi \phi \to \psi \phi$. That is an important piece of information. You should clearly mention this in the problem.

Comment: @Fluctuations - See the thing is, for the same Lagrangian, I could have computed the scattering amplitude for $\phi \phi \to \phi \phi$ or $\psi \psi \to \psi \psi$ each of which would have different answers even though the theory is the same. Thus, to even discuss a scattering amplitude, you need to give the theory _and_ the exact process that you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you Prahar. Sorry, I do apologize for all the mess I made around here. The thing is I am really confused about this and how to proceed that I didn't even understand the problem. @Prahar does this process have a name so I can read about it to know how to proceed with this. Or what are the specific Feynmann rules for this theory.. Your help and time are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as usual:

1. Derive (or find somewhere) the Feynman rules for this theory.
2. Draw the lowest-order diagrams contributing to the specific scattering process you are interested in
3. Evaluate them

It should be even easier than in case of QED (I believe you studied electron-electron scatterings in QED)

UPD: this is called the pseudo-scalar Yukawa theory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this theory have a name in order to check for the rules on line?

Comment: It is called pseudo-scalar Yukawa theory. Be aware that there is also a scalar Yukawa theory without the $\gamma^5$ matrix and it differs from yours.

Comment: Would it differ if I added to the above lagrangian  $$1/2\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - 1/2 m^2 \phi^2 -1/4! \lambda \phi^4$$ I mean would it affect my Feynmann rules for this.

Comment: Yes, a new type of propagating particle (in context of Yukawa interaction it is usually called a meson) would appear. The third term also adds the meson self-interaction vertex.